# Access: Changes don't appear in my subform when I enter a new record

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a form that contains the user interface, and there I have a subform that reads data from a form. When I double click to a record, a second subform pops up and I enter the new details there

The problem I have is when I add a new record and click the save button I created, the subform doesn't reflect the changes.
I have to close the form of the UI and open it again to see the new record, or go to the table

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply Requery the SubForm. You can [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)